# C# Multithread dequeue List<string>

Tags: c#, string, multithreading, list

First of all, sorry for my english. I'm doing some C# exercices but I'm in a trouble with this.

Actually, I need to create  2 threads using Thread class. These threads needs to Dequeue items from a List (I have created a Dequeue method to do that) but I need to configure these 2 threads to Deqeueue this List at the same time. Aditionaly, this method needs to show the thread that executed him and the removed the object.

That's the method called by Thread:

```
    private static object Lock = new object();
    public string Consume()
    {
        string result = "";
        while (StringList.Count > 0)
        {
            lock (Lock)
            {
                result = Dequeue();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

And the thread call:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(() => { Console.WriteLine("Thread 1: " + QC.Consume()); });
Thread t2 = new Thread(() => { Console.WriteLine("Thread 2: " + QC.Consume()); });
t1.Start();
t2.Start();
```

Actually, the program "is working" but it is only being executed by an unique thread. I don't know how to dequeue items from list at the same time with different threads + show which thread dequeued the item.

I'm not asking just to know if someone know the problem, I want to understand the problem and solve it.

Thanks to all!

Comment: `List<T>` class is not [thread safe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netcore-3.1#thread-safety). You shouldn't access a `Count` property from different threads.

Comment: Use [Thread-Safe Collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/). For example, `ConcurrentQueue`

Comment: Was looking at this Class but the problem that I'm exposing wants me to do something with List class instead of a thread-safe classes.